# How to return mocked Data in Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Suppose we have this method in a service that return an Observable:

```
getSearchResults(request: LocationSearchRequest){
      return this.http.get(this.getApiUrl(request))
            .map(res => <LocationSearchResponse> res.json())    
            .catch(this.handleError);    
}
```

How can I modify this code to return the mocked data ratehr then making an actual GET requesr?

```
import { MOCKEDDATA } from './mocked-data';
```

It's not a duplicate question. This has nothing to do with testing, jasmine and angualr2 testing api.

Comment: The solution was to use Observable.of();

Why is it marked as duplicate? This has nothing to do with testing, jasmine and angular2 testing api.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Xavi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43115910/2501304)'s answer is great and simple, but it didn't work for me - I tweaked it like so:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

And then:

```
return of(MOCKEDDATA);
```

Hope this helps someone else too!

Comment: This is the syntax in newer versions of rxjs

Answer (score 15):

I had the same topic some time ago. It is also possible to use the method:

> Observable.create()

It was solved by the code below (using typescript):

```
getElementTemplateNames() : Observable<string[]> {
let names : string[] = MockedElementData.getNames();
return Observable.create( observer => {
    observer.next(names);
    observer.complete();
});}
```

*MockedElementData* holds the data.

The import statement for Observable is:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do:

`Observable.of(MOCKEDDATA)`

You can also add a delay:

`Observable.of(MOCKEDDATA).delay(1000)`

Comment: This no longer works: a functioning version can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50866461/748253

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this issue with the following code.

```
 this.treeService
          .getData()
          .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
          .subscribe(
            (fa) => {              
              this.Items = fa.map(f => new TreeviewItem(f));                          
              console.log('this.Items', this.Items);              
            }
          );
```

Take in consideration that your tree nodes needs to have in all levels.
text: "text"
value: "value"