# How can I create an observable with a delay

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

### Question

For testing purposes, I'm creating `Observable` objects that replace the observable that would be returned by an actual http call with `Http`.

My observable is created with the following code:

```ts
fakeObservable = Observable.create(obs => {
  obs.next([1, 2, 3]);
  obs.complete();
});
```

The thing is, this observable emits immediatly. Is there a way to add a custom delay to its emission?

---

### Track

I tried this:

```ts
fakeObservable = Observable.create(obs => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    obs.next([1, 2, 3]);
    obs.complete();
  }, 100);
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/delay.md

Comment: I tried to chain `.create(...)` with `.delay(1000)` but it didn't work: Observable_1.Observable.create(...).delay is not a function.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: are you subscribing to the observable?

Comment: Fake the Http response delay with my own observable. @shusson yeah, the class I'm testing is calling the service (I'm trying to mock) for the observable in order to subscribe to it.

Comment: Actually your example should just work...hmmm

Comment: I guess I'll just test my http calls without any delay

Comment: An observable does not "resolve". It "emits".

Comment: Why setTimeout doesnt work here? Anybody?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Using the following imports:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
```

Try this:

```
let fakeResponse = [1,2,3];
let delayedObservable = Observable.of(fakeResponse).delay(5000);
delayedObservable.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

**UPDATE: RXJS 6**

The above solution doesn't really work anymore in newer versions of RXJS (and of angular for example).

So the scenario is that I have an array of items to check with an API with. The API only accepts a single item, and I do not want to kill the API by sending all requests at once. So I need a timed release of items on the Observable stream with a small delay in between.

Use the following imports:

```
import { from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/internal/operators';
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/internal/operators';
```

Then use the following code:

```
const myArray = [1,2,3,4];

from(myArray).pipe(
        concatMap( item => of(item).pipe ( delay( 1000 ) ))
    ).subscribe ( timedItem => {
        console.log(timedItem)
    });
```

It basically creates a new 'delayed' Observable for every item in your array. There are probably many other ways of doing it, but this worked fine for me, and complies with the 'new' RXJS format.

Comment: Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'. Do you import your Observable with `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';`?

Comment: Yep, I use .of extensively so I guess something strange is up with your rx dependencies..

Comment: I mean you confirm you're not importing with `import {Observable} from 'rxjs'`? If yes, I have some investigation to do...

Comment: I am importing as import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'

Comment: Did you have any success?

Comment: From this page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs. I deduced I had to explicitly import with `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';`. Do you happen to do the same thing? It's still odd though, since it won't chain with .delay(...) and it shows an error when I try `rxjs/add/observable/delay`...

Comment: I managed to make it work in a non-testing environment with the import: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay'` which adds clarity to the problem. The thing is, in a testing environment, jasmine is not waiting for the delay when calling `fixture.detectChanges()`

Comment: I have never had those issues I'm afraid, so I can't help you with that..

Comment: Sure, the testing stuff is kind of off-topic here, but I should be able to handle it now that the way rxjs is imported is clearer for me.

Comment: Understood. I approved your edits for others that have the same issues.

Comment: What about an observable which throws an error with delay?

Comment: should  `of(item.pipe ( delay( 1000 ) ))` be `of(item))).pipe(delay(1000)` trying to pipe the array gave me errors

Comment: I believe the updated function is structured incorrectly. @AdrianBer formed the correct answer.

Comment: This is what worked for me with rxjs6:
    from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]).pipe(concatMap(num => of(num).pipe(delay(1000))))
      .subscribe(x => console.log(x));

Comment: @robert same, `of(item).pipe( delay(1000) )` worked. `of(item.pipe...` is incorrect

Comment: @MikeOne 's solution worked for me too. Sad that so much code is necessary for such a simple matter...

Answer (score 169):

In RxJS 5+ you can do it like this

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { of } from "rxjs/observable/of";
import { delay } from "rxjs/operators";

fakeObservable = of('dummy').pipe(delay(5000));
```

In RxJS 6+

```
import { of } from "rxjs";
import { delay } from "rxjs/operators";

fakeObservable = of('dummy').pipe(delay(5000));
```

If you want to delay each emitted value try

```
from([1, 2, 3]).pipe(concatMap(item => of(item).pipe(delay(1000))));
```

Comment: The cleanest solution in my opinion.

Comment: This "solution" only works if you emit one item.  The delay operator is not invoked for each element in an observable.  That is why the horrid concatMap solution is required.

Comment: @RickO'Shea, the question is about one emitted value, so that's why this solution.

Comment: So fresh and so clean !

Comment: I updated my answer for multiple delays @RickO'Shea

Answer (score 19):

What you want is a timer:

```
// RxJS v6+
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

//emit [1, 2, 3] after 1 second.
const source = timer(1000).map(([1, 2, 3]);
//output: [1, 2, 3]
const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: Good answer, don't forget to unsubscribe

Comment: @Sami this specific instance of `timer` doesn't need to be unsubscribed (it will auto complete after 1 second). This is because `timer` isn't using the second argument of interval which would need to have extra code to mark it completed some how.

Answer (score 8):

It's little late to answer ... but just in case may be someone return to this question looking for an answer

'delay' is property(function) of an Observable

```
fakeObservable = Observable.create(obs => {
  obs.next([1, 2, 3]);
  obs.complete();
}).delay(3000);
```

This worked for me ...

Comment: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay'`  gives this error now:  **Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/delay'**

Comment: Why would you call you observable fake when it's quite real? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `asyncScheduler`, it schedules tasks asynchronously, by putting them on the JavaScript event loop queue. It is best used to delay tasks in time or to schedule tasks repeating in intervals.

[Link to the documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/asyncScheduler)

Answer (score -2):

**`import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';`**

We should add the above import to make the blow code to work

```
Let obs = Rx.Observable
    .interval(1000).take(3);

obs.subscribe(value => console.log('Subscriber: ' + value));
```

Comment: import * is a bit of an overkill for this simple task