# Simulate long response in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I need to simulate a long response from server in Angular 2 for education purposes. I have code

```
getTasks() : Observable<Task[]> {
    return this.http.get('data/tasks.json').map(response =>  {
        return response.json();
    });
}

// using 
getTasks().subscribe(groups => {
   this.tasks = groups;
});
```

and need server response for at least 1 sec. In Angular 1.5 I did this in this way

```
 this.getTasks = function () {
    return $http.get("data/tasks.json").then(function (response) {
        return $timeout(function () {
            return response.data;
        }, 1000);
    };
}
```

In Angular 2 according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413969/how-can-i-create-an-observable-with-a-delay) I tried

```
getTasks() : Observable<Task[]> {
    return this.http.get('data/tasks.json').map(response =>  {            
        return Observable.of(response.json()).delay(1000);
    });
}
```

and

```
getTasks() : Observable<Task[]> {
    return this.http.get('data/tasks.json').map(response =>  {
       return Observable.create((obs: Observable<Task[]>) => {
            obs.next(response.json());
            obs.complete();
       ).delay(1000);        
    });
}
```

but have TypeScript compilation error or `getTasks().subscribe` gets and Observable and not tasks collection. Looks like I missed something. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is caused due to a type mismatch. Your `getTasks` method is stated to return type `Observable<Task[]>` However the map method is returning an observable instead of an array (of type Task[]). You only need to return the observable as normal then add the delay method to delay the observable emit.

```
getTasks() : Observable<Task[]> {
    return this.http.get('data/tasks.json').map(response =>  {
       return response.json();  
    })
    .delay(1000);
}
```