# Delay for every element with RXJS

Tags: rxjs

I'm using RxViz to simulate different actions that comes every 1 sec. When I try

```
Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
  obs.next([1, 2, 3]); // or could be ['aaa', 'bbbb', 'ccc']
  obs.complete();
}).delay(1000);
```

on https://rxviz.com

or on my own with a console.log

it keeps displaying the three number 1, 2, 3 at the same time

There's a post about this same problem, but none of the answer works for me. I'm using Rx last version 6

[How can I create an observable with a delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413969/how-can-i-create-an-observable-with-a-delay)

[EDIT] The array can contains anything like number, string or any object

Comment: You want to delay each value in the array or the entire array as is?

Comment: I want to delay each value by 1 second, and each element could be anything like number, string, object

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to delay each value (by 1 sec for example), you may do something like the following:

```
 Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
      obs.next([1, 2, 3]);
      obs.complete();
    })
      .pipe(
        // make observable to emit each element of the array (not the whole array)
        mergeMap((x: [any]) => from(x)),
        // delay each element by 1 sec
        concatMap(x => of(x).pipe(delay(1000)))
      )
      .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
  }
```

Here I did not modify the internals of the observable created by you. Instead, I just take your observable and apply appropriate operations to achieve what you seem to be expecting.

Comment: If think your solution is nice. Made me look for the `concatMap`. Once thing, `of` operator does not take array and deconstruct it. the `from` operator does. After that, you need to apply a second concatMap to do the conversion of each value in the array into an observable with the delay apply to it

Comment: I tried on rxviz, it only display a Cross icon, I had to convert your code to rxJs 5:

Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
  obs.next([1, 2, 3]);
  obs.complete();
})
  .concatMap(x=>of(x)
 .delay(1000)
)

Comment: I also tried running it in local, and all the array display in one time instead of emitting each value after each second:

Observable.create(obs => {
  obs.next([1, 2, 3]);
  obs.complete();
}).pipe( 
concatMap(x=>Observable.of(x)),
delay(1000) 
)
.subscribe(a => console.log(a))

Comment: @John Please check my updated answer with tested working code.

Comment: Great solution, thank you! Simple and effective. I found some awful beasts before this :)

Answer (score 12):

Here is my solution (very clean)

```
const fakeData = [1,2,3]

loadData$() {
    return from(fakeData).pipe(
      concatMap(item => of(item).pipe(
        delay(1000)
      )),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

This one works by modifying a little bit @siva636's answer

```
Rx.Observable.create(obs => { 
  obs.next(1); 
  obs.next(2); 
  obs.next(3); 
  obs.complete(); 
}.concatMap(x=>Rx.Observable.of(x) .delay(1000) )
```

Comment: good and clean answer, with rxjs 6 you should remember about .pipe operator after .of(x)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a succinct way that builds on the other responses.

```js
from([...Array(10).keys()]).pipe(
    concatMap(x => of(x).pipe(delay(1000)))
).subscribe(y => console.log(y))
```

A more RxJs native version would be as follows.

```js
const myInterval = rxjs.interval(1000);
myInterval.pipe(rxjs.operators.take(10)).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, you emit in one observable emission the all array. `[1,2,3]`. 
You only delay that one emission by 1000 ms. But the emission is still one.

Even if we emit each value on its own, the delay function will only apply to the first emission. The others will come immediately after:

```
Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
  var arr = [1, 2, 3];
  arr.forEach(item => obs.next(item));
  obs.complete();
}).delay(1000);
```

There is no magic in the `create` constructing function. If we want an emission to come every `x` time:

We could make an interval that emits those values (taken from [learnrxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/create.html))

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

/*
  Increment value every 1s, emit even numbers.
*/
const evenNumbers = Observable.create(function(observer) {
  let value = 0;
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    observer.next(value);
    value++;
  }, 1000);

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Comment: setInterval is not what I'm looking for, the array in my example is an array of int, but it could be anything like string, or an object. If I use Observable.create, the solution could be something like in pseudo code:

Observable.create(obs => {
   observer.next('aaaa');
observer.delay(1000); // does not work
observer.next('bbbb');
observer.delay(1000);
observer.next('cccc');

});

Answer (score 1):

RxJS v7 supports the operator `delayWhen` [1], so you could write a simpler code as

```js
import { delayWhen, interval, of } from 'rxjs';

of("John", "von", "Neumman", "János Neumann").pipe(
  delayWhen((_, index) => interval(index*1000))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Check out a demo on https://stackblitz.com/edit/vgibzv?file=index.ts

It works because it delays the emission of items by 0 seconds, 1000 seconds, 2000 seconds, 3000 seconds, and so on.

Another choice is the operator `scan`, you make the series from an interval [2].

[1] "RxJS - delayWhen." 16 Dec. 2022, https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/delayWhen

[2] "RxJS - scan." 16 Dec. 2022, rxjs.dev/api/index/function/scan

Answer (score 0):

The good with rxjs is that it is easy to compose custom operators from existing ones. e.g. in your case the `delayPerElement` operator:

```js
import { delay, concatMap, of, map } from 'rxjs';

//Compose a custom operator
const delayPerElement = (delayMs)=>concatMap(x => of(x).pipe(delay(delayMs)))

from([1,2,3,4,5])
.pipe(delayPerElement(1000))
.subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

**output:** (a number is printed every second)

```
1
2 
3 
4 
5
```

You can go further and create a `delayedMap`

```js
//Compose a custom operator
const delayedMap = (mapperFunc, delayMs)=>pipe(map(mapperFunc),delayPerElement(delayMs));


from([1,2,3,4,5])
.pipe(delayedMap(x=>x*2), 1000)
.subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

**output:** (a number is printed every second)

```
2
4 
5 
8 
10
```

or even further with `delayedConcatMap` (e.g. useful for delay between web requests)

```js
//Compose a custom operator
const delayedConcatMap = (...args)=>pipe(delayedMap(...args), concatAll());

from([1,2,3,4,5])
.pipe(delayedConcatMap(x=>axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${x}`).then(j=>j.data.title), 1000) )
.subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

**output:** (a text is printed every second)

```
delectus aut autem
quis ut nam facilis et officia qui
fugiat veniam minus
et porro tempora
laboriosam mollitia et enim quasi adipisci quia provident illum
```