# Multiple sequential AJAX requests RXJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am trying to make multiple AJAX request sequentially with some delay in each request. I would expect sequential response from each request. I have tried **mergeMap** rxjs operator. It works well but I want the response with some delay. Currently I am getting the response for each request sequentially but I need some delay in each response.

```js
import { of, from, interval } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';

const items = [1,2,3,4,5];

const requests = from(items)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(item => ajax.getJSON(`https://api.github.com/users/${item}`)),  
);
 requests.subscribe(
      data => console.log(data), //process item or push it to array 
      err => console.log(err)
);
```

Here is the stackbliz example.

[Multiple AJAX request RXJS](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-csjm6w?devtoolsheight=60)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by utilising the [delay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/delay) operator.

But first, you will need to use `concatMap` on each element on the items `observable` array, such that a new observable with the delay time is created for every item on the `items` array.

```
const items = [1,2,3,4,5];

const requests = from(items)
    .pipe(
      concatMap(item => ajax.getJSON(`https://api.github.com/users/${item}`)
        .pipe(
           delay(1000),
        )
    ),  
);
 requests.subscribe(
      data => console.log(data), //process item or push it to array 
      err => console.log(err)
);
```

I have forked a new demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-y6v7mi?file=index.ts).

Comment: Thanks but it is still giving me observable in response. I need actual response data.

Answer (score 0):

```
from(items)
```

will create a 'cold observable' what means the entire array will proceed immediately. If you want to add a delay before sending a request (not to send requests at once) try using zip and an interval

```
import { interval, zip } from 'rxjs';
import { flatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
const interval$ = interval(1000);
const requests$ = zip(from(items), interval$)
  .pipe(
    flatMap(([itmes]) => items),
    mergeMap(item => ajax.getJSON(`https://api.github.com/users/${item}`))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with `delay`:)

```js
const items = [1,2,3,4,5];

const requests = from(items)
    .pipe(
        mergeMap(item => ajax.getJSON(`https://api.github.com/users/${item}`)),
        // delay each element by 1 sec
        concatMap(x => of(x).pipe(delay(1000)))
      );

 requests.subscribe(
      data => console.log(data), //process item or push it to array 
      err => console.log(err)
);
```

Similar case here:

[Delay for every element with RXJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50886975/delay-for-every-element-with-rxjs)

More info about delay:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/delay