# Delay ngFor loop

Tags: angular, ngfor, google-directions-api

I'm working on google maps directions, as per API,  I can only make 10 request per sec.

Below is my code,

```
<div *ngFor="let place of outstation_routes" class="item">
  <figure class="wo-vehicles-img">
      <agm-map [zoom]="1">
          <agm-direction [origin]="place.origin" [destination]="place.destination">
          </agm-direction>
      </agm-map>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Issue now is, google is throwing this error `message: "DIRECTIONS_ROUTE: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT:`

So how can I overcome this issue, please guide

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps, Push data to the array after every 1 second.

```js
getOutstationRoutes() {
    this.service
      .getOutstationRoutes()
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(x => from(x)),
        concatMap(x => of(x).pipe(delay(1000)))
      )
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.outstation_routes.push(res);
      });
 }
```

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cy9e39)
Found the answer for pushing data [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50887027/11719787)