# RxJS emit array of strings, one second apart from each other

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a block of code that is responsible for taking an `Observable<string[]>`, then mapping that to `Observable<string>` and emitting the values 1 second apart from each other.

Think of this like a message ticker on a website.

My current code is working below:

```
    const arrayOfStrings$ = of([
        'Warming things up',
        'Getting things ready',
        'Welcome'
    ]);

    this.messages$ = arrayOfStrings$.pipe(
        switchMap((messages) => from(messages).pipe(
            concatMap((innerMessage) => of(innerMessage).pipe(delay(1000))),
        )),
        tap((message) => {
            console.log(`Message: ${message}`);
        })
    );
```

Is there a better way to do this with less code? It's mainly the `switchMap()` and `concatMap()` inside each other that is bothering me.

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

**Edit: This is a simplified version of what I have running in my actual project. I am just trying to find an easier way to go from an Observable<string[]> to an Observable and delay each emission one second apart after each emission**

Comment: you should look there https://stackoverflow.com/a/50866461/8471329

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `concatMap()` and `delay()` operators to make sure that each emission will be delivered one-by-one with a specified time interval.

```
const arrayOfStrings = [
  'Warming things up',
  'Getting things ready',
  'Welcome'
];

(from(arrayOfStrings)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(message => 
      of(message).pipe(delay(1_000))
    ),
  )
  .subscribe()
);
```

Comment: Thanks! This really make the code more readable!

Answer (score 1):

```
of('one', 'two', 'three')
  .pipe(zipWith(interval(1000)))
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

or if you want to start immediately replace interval with

```
timer(0, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following code:

```
const arrayOfStrings$ = of([
  'Warming things up',
  'Getting things ready',
  'Welcome'
]);

arrayOfStrings$.pipe(
  mergeMap((a) => a),
  zip(timer(1000, 1000)),
  map(([a]) => a),
  tap(message => {
    console.log(`Message: ${message}`);
  })
);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a shot. fromArray() was deprecated in favor of from(), in the version of rxjs I'm using (v6). I cannot change the value of arrayOfStrings$, because in my project code this is connected to the output of a subject<string[]>. Left that detail out because I wanted to simplify the problem. I'm starting with a Observable<string[]> and I want to end with Observable<string> spaced 1 second apart

Comment: @DamianC I updated my code to use the original definition of `arrayOfStrings$`. The `mergeMap` with the identity function, _unpacks_ the strings of the subject<string[]>.